# Wicket AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior refreshes the full page when opened with 2 browser tags

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I have a label that checks for new notifications every 5 seconds and updates its text to represent the current notification count by using AjaxSelfUpdatingTimeBehaviour.
All is good until I open another browser tab with the same page, then on both tabs instead of updating the label, AjaxSelfUpdatingTimeBehaviour starts refreshing the page every 5 seconds.

```
 private void initializeNotificationPanel() {
    EventNotificationService notificationService = EventNotificationService
            .getInstanceOfNotificationService();
    List<Event> list = notificationService
            .getSubscribedEvents(MyFoodSession.get().getUser());
    final User currentUser = MyFoodSession.get().getUser();
    final Label countLabel;
    final WebMarkupContainer wmc = new WebMarkupContainer("markupContainer");
    wmc.setOutputMarkupId(true);

    final ListView<Event> listView = initListView(list);
    wmc.add(listView);
    listView.setVisible(false);
    listView.setOutputMarkupId(true);

    final AjaxLink<String> notificationLink = initializeAjaxLink(wmc,
            listView);

    if (notificationService.hasNotifications(currentUser)) {
        countLabel = new Label("countlbl", list.size());
    } else {
        countLabel = new Label("countlbl", "0");
    }

    countLabel.add(new AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(5)) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        EventNotificationService notificationService = EventNotificationService
                .getInstanceOfNotificationService();

        @Override
        protected final void onPostProcessTarget(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            if (notificationService.hasNotifications(currentUser)) {
                countLabel.setDefaultModelObject(""
                        + notificationService.getSubscribedEvents(
                                MyFoodSession.get().getUser()).size());
            } else {
                countLabel.setDefaultModelObject("0");
            }

        }
    });
    wmc.add(notificationLink);
    notificationLink.add(countLabel);
    add(wmc);

}
```

Comment: heven't you fixed this? i have same behavior without additional tabs, one tab is enough

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a reason why AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior should expose this behavior. You should create a quickstart and attache it to a new Jira issue.